# Generalized Isomorphism Theorem for Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Consider the following:

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and $\phi:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ B$ a group homomorphism. Let $T$ be a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{im}\phi$, and let $Q = \lbrace x \in A :\  \phi(x) \in T \rbrace $.

I have managed to show that $Q$ is a normal subgroup of A. Now I conjecture:

$$ \frac{A}{Q} = \frac{\text{im}(\phi)}{T} $$

But I'm not sure how to show this in general.

Comment: In general, $T$ need not be a subgroup of $\operatorname{im}\phi$, so this cannot be true!

Comment: I re-read what I had done and I realized I didn't need it to be a normal subgroup of B, but just the image of $\phi$

Comment: @Servaes thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the map $\phi$, by the first isomorphism theorem we have an isomorphism
$$\overline{\phi}:\ A/\ker\phi\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{im}\phi.$$
Because $T$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{im}\phi$ we have a surjective group homomorphism
$$\pi:\ \operatorname{im}\phi\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{im}\phi/T.$$
Because $\phi$ and $\pi$ are both surjective, also $\psi:=\pi\circ\phi$ is a surjective group homomorphism 
$$\psi:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{im}\phi/T,$$
so $\operatorname{im}\psi=\operatorname{im}\phi/T$, and $\ker\psi=Q$ by definition. So again by the first isomorphism theorem we have a group isomorphism
$$\overline{\psi}:\ A/Q\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{im}\phi/T.$$

Comment: This is clever, I didn't think of reusing the first isomorphism theorem to prove its own generalization

Comment: I guess this shows that your generalisation is in fact equivalent to the first isomorphism theorem :)