# $G \cong H$ and $G$ is simple. Then $H$ is simple as well.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, simple-groups

I think it must be true. Yet I have no rigorous proof for that. So, what I need to prove is that "group being simple" is invariant under isomorphism.

That if $G \cong H$, then either both are simple groups, or both are not simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Let $f:H\to G$ be an isomorphism and let $K\subseteq H$ be a normal subgroup.  What can you say about $f(K)\subseteq G$?

Comment: I see. If $K$ is a proper nontrivial subgroup of $H$, then $f(K) \neq {e_G}$ since $f$ is injective, and $f(K) \neq G$ for the same reason, so $f(K)$ is a proper nontrivial subgroup of $G$. Now, for any $t \in f(K)$ and for any $g \in G$ we have $t = f(k)$ for some $k$, and $g = f(h)$ for some $h$, so $gtg^{-1} = f(hkh^{-1}) \in f(K)$ since $K$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall a group is simple if it doesn't have a normal subgroup other than itself and the identity group, or put another way "no non trivial normal subgroup".

So a natural proof by contradiction arises.

Since $G \cong H$ we can consider an isomorphism $\pi: H \rightarrow G$.

Suppose now that $H$ has a non trivial normal subgroup $K$. we will show that $\pi(K)$ must be a non trivial normal subgroup of $G$.

1. $\pi(K)$ has the same number of elements as $K$ since $\pi$ is an bijection (since isomorphisms are bijections), so if it is a subgroup of G, then it must be a non trivial subgroup.
2. This question: [Generalized Isomorphism Theorem for Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447701/generalized-isomorphism-theorem-for-groups), shows that the images of normal groups of $H$ must be normal subgroups of $G$ under the isomorphism $\pi$
3. We combine both, to conclude that $\pi(K)$ is a normal subgroup of G, AND is a non trivial subgroup (so it isn't the whole group or the identity), thus it MUST be a non trivial normal subgroup, a contradiction if we started by assuming $G$ is simple.
4. Thus we conclude that if $G$ is simple and $G \cong H$ then it must be the case that $H$ is simple.